# Ошибка ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5' в pychar, AttributeError: module has no attribute 'Ui_MainWindow'

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt

я новичок в питоне и столкнулся ошибкой, описанной ниже. Все что нашел по этой проблеме не помогло.
[image: Код:]
Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import stat

class StatApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, stat.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self);

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = StatApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В случае запуска в pychar выбрасывает ошибку 
Ошибка ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5' 
пробовал установить pyqt5 заново, проверил в project interpreter, даже среда подсказывает при использовании QtWidgets импортировать из PyQt5
[image: project interpreter]

при запуске файла из консоли ошибка 
AttributeError: module 'stat' has no attribute 'Ui_MainWindow'
хотя в файле stat.py Ui_MainWindow явно есть.
[image: stat.py конвертированный из stat.ui]
stat.py конвертированный из stat.ui:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(263, 175)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 243, 81))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_13)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_14)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_15)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_16)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 100, 81, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 263, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "17 мин 3 с"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Количество обработанных снимков:"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "350"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Количество оставшихся снимков:"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "6"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Среднее время на снимок:"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "0,01с"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Время до окончания цикла:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Остановить"))
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Питоне уже есть модуль `stat`.
Замените `import stat` на `import myStat`

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

#import stat
import myStat                                                   # <<<=====

class StatApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, myStat.Ui_MainWindow): 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self);

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = StatApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**myStat.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(263, 175)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 243, 81))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_10)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_13)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_14)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_15)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.label_16)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(174, 100, 81, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 263, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "17 мин 3 с"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Количество обработанных снимков:"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "350"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Количество оставшихся снимков:"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "6"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Среднее время на снимок:"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "0,01с"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Время до окончания цикла:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Остановить"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]